# Javascript using mouse hover class to effect child ids

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the class navButtons effect all of the ids inside it using the mouse over  effect. I read on here that you can do this with a for loop but that would require changing the names of the ids. is there a way to do this without changing the names?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons").style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons").style.color = "black";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navButtons">
      <div id="about">about</div>
      <div id="portfolio">portfolio</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use css to add hover effect to all `div` inside `.navButtons` div.

```css
.navButtons div{
 color: red;
}
.navButtons div:hover{
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Hover effect</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="navButtons">
      <div id="about">about</div>
      <div id="portfolio">portfolio</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>   
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ha! no wonder I couldn't find anything about how to do this in javascript thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to apply styles to all the elements inside `navButtons` when hovering `navButtons`. This can be done with CSS only.

```css
.navButtons:hover > div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navButtons">
      <div id="about">about</div>
      <div id="portfolio">portfolio</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

If you however, for some reason, want to use Javascript instead (not recommended for this purpose) you can do the following:

```js
var navButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('navButtons')[0];
var children = navButtons.getElementsByTagName('div');
  
navButtons.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
});

navButtons.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].style.color = 'black';
  }
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navButtons">
      <div id="about">about</div>
      <div id="portfolio">portfolio</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);`
you are trying to add event listener to a node list, you will have to attach it each node inside the list using a loop. then you can access the current element inside the `mouseOver()` function using `event.target`.

```js
var navButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButtons");
for (var i=0; i<navButtons.length; i++){
  navButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
  navButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
}
function mouseOver(event) {
    event.target.parentNode.style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOut(event) {
    event.target.parentNode.style.color = "black";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navButtons">
      <div id="about">about</div>
      <div id="portfolio">portfolio</div>
      <div id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the children of the class by this method

```
var c = document.getElementById("navButtons").children;
```

c is now an Array. So you can iterate over this array, thereby having contact with each child
i.e `c[0]` is the first element